# Updating a row with a select query

Tags: sql

I am trying to move the result of the select query to the `recamt` row where the `lastrecdate` is the maximum date, but while I'm using update query for the table below it is giving me an error. I tried to link the cardno record with this subquery.

*Subquery:*

```
SELECT cardno
FROM Tbl_Emi e2
WHERE LastRecDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND e2.CardNo = e.CardNo
```

---

```
UPDATE Tbl_Emi
SET  RecAmt =
(
    SELECT
    (
        SELECT extraamt
        FROM Tbl_Emi e1
        WHERE LastRecDate = (SELECT MIN(lastrecdate) FROM Tbl_Emi)
            AND e1.CardNo=e.CardNo
    ) 
    +
    (
        SELECT pendamt+trnammt
        FROM Tbl_Emi e2
        WHERE LastRecDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND e2.CardNo = e.CardNo
    )
    FROM Tbl_Emi e WHERE e.lastrecdate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
)
WHERE tbl_emi.lastrecdate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)




        Cardno      |     EMI     |   Recamt   |      Trndt     |   Sts   |   PendAmt   |   Trnamt   |    Extra    

 5140560000001183   |   1016.00   |    0.00    |   2014-05-23   |    R    |   0.00      |    1017    |     13

 5140560000001191   |   880.00    |    0.00    |   2014-05-23   |    R    |   0.00      |    880     |     0

 5140560000001142   |   934.00    |    0.00    |   2014-05-23   |    P    |   0.00      |    500     |     0

 5140560000001209   |   963.00    |    0.00    |   2014-05-23   |    P    |   0.00      |    600     |     0

 5140560000001175   |   1024.00   |    0.00    |   2014-05-23   |    N    |   0.00      |    0       |     0

 5140560000001167   |   1117.00   |    0.00    |   2014-05-23   |    N    |   0.00      |    0       |     0

 5140560000001159   |   834.00    |    0.00    |   2014-05-23   |    N    |   0.00      |    0       |     0

 5140560000001183   |   1016.00   |    0.00    |   2014-05-25   |    N    |   30.00     |    1017    |     0

 5140560000001191   |   880.00    |    0.00    |   2014-05-25   |    N    |   0.00      |    880     |     0

 5140560000001142   |   934.00    |    0.00    |   2014-05-25   |    N    |   0.00      |    500     |     0

 5140560000001209   |   963.00    |    0.00    |   2014-05-25   |    N    |   0.00      |    600     |     0

 5140560000001175   |   1024.00   |    0.00    |   2014-05-25   |    N    |   0.00      |    0       |     0

 5140560000001167   |   1117.00   |    0.00    |   2014-05-25   |    N    |   0.00      |    0       |     0

 5140560000001159   |   834.00    |    0.00    |   2014-05-25   |    N    |   0.00      |    0       |     0
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should tell what error you get and which SQL Server you are using. From your code i guess you use MSSQL.

However, your query refers to column "lastrecdate" which is not in your table, so that code cannot work on that sample data anyway.

Update: After the comments that would be my proposed solution. Unfortunatetly i'm still not quite clear about the expected solution and the fact that the column names do not match is also confusing.

```
UPDATE upd SET Recamt=calc.recamt_total --update each row ith calculated values
FROM Tbl_Emi upd -- Join the calculated update value per CardNo to each row
JOIN (
        SELECT te.CardNo,textra.extraamt+te.pentamt+te.trnamt recamt_total --join values from today
        FROM Tbl_Emi te
            JOIN  (SELECT t1.CardNo, t1.extraamt --extraamt value at min_dat
                   FROM Tbl_Emi t1 
                       JOIN (SELECT t2.CardNo,MIN(t2.Trndt) as min_dat --min_dat for each CardNo
                             FROM Tbl_Emi t2
                             GROUP BY t2.CardNo) mindat ON mindat.CardNo=t1.CardNo AND mindat.min_dat=t1.Trndat
                  ) textra ON textra.CardNo=te.CardNo
        WHERE te.Trndat=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    ) calc ON upd.CardNo=calc.CardNo
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvience the trnamt was suppose to be lastrecdate and the error is: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The Trnamt column in your sample data has numerical values, maybe you mean Trndat?

Comment: Sorry again it is trndat.

Comment: You try to do something like variable=(SELECT foo FROM bar). In that case, the result of SELECT foo FROM bar must be a single value. The error you receive tells you, that SELECT foo FROM bar returns more values and the SQL server does not know how he should compare a table to a single variable. Can you tell more in detail what your data means and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Correct this is the point, now I want to know how can I link them, known that the link will be within the cardno where the date is tdays date and the cardno of the pervious date just like the way it is linked in the select query, but I cannot find a way to link it from the update query

Comment: So for each CardNo you want extraamt for the smallest date and pendamt+trnamt for the current date and put the sum of them into Recamt, is that correct? If yes, do you want to update all Rows of the CardNo with the same Recamt value?

Comment: it is correct, yes all rows of today's date need to be updated

Comment: I also tries to link them by this update query but still it is showing the same error.

Comment: update  Tbl_Emi   set  RecAmt =
 
  (
 
  select
 
  (select extraamt from Tbl_Emi e1 where LastRecDate=(SELECT MIN(lastrecdate) FROM Tbl_Emi) and e1.CardNo=e.CardNo  ) 

  +
 
  (select pendamt+trnammt from Tbl_Emi e2 where LastRecDate=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) and e2.CardNo=e.CardNo )
 
  from Tbl_Emi e where e.lastrecdate=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
 
  )
 
  where CardNo=
 
  (
 
  select
 
  (select CardNo from Tbl_Emi e2 where LastRecDate=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) and e2.CardNo=e.CardNo)
 
  from Tbl_Emi e where e.lastrecdate=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
 
  )

Comment: and lastrecdate=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))

Comment: I think that your database design is a little flawed but i assume you have to work with it. Are you required to get your update in one single statement or can you split it up? One statement will be possible but i don't think it will be very helpful for understanding.

Comment: I can give it a try to use in one statement and see the resuls, but I never used it before so can you pleae advise how to do that.

Comment: I updated the answer with a proposal, you can try if it works